# How to find out programmatically added textfields in a scrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4

Inside my scrollView i am adding uitextfields programmatically by clicking an "ADD" Button. the number of textfields depending on how much i press in add button. it can be 'N' number of textfields. 
After this fields editing how can i get values inside the all textfields into an array.
 if once i edited textfield there is a possibility to delete entry inside that. So what is the way to save values in the all text fields while clicking in Save button.
i am attaching my screenshot with this.
Thanks in Advance
[image: Programmatically adding Textfields sample preview]

Comment: When ever you add textfield on add button click at that time you need to set text field tag property so it will help you to identify textfiel value and also you can able to add these values in array. textfielt.tag = count;

Comment: Hi access your textField using tagValue...

Comment: why don't you work with `UITableView`? you could manage easily to add or remove any cell to/from the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use fast enumeration.

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutablearray....];
for (UIView *subV in self.view.subviews){
     if([subV isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]){
        //store it in a NSDictionary, so later can still know which 
        //textField your text belongs,
         NSDictionary *tempDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectAndKey:subV.txt 
                           ,subV.tag,/*or subVw.placeholder*/,nil];
        [arr addObject:tempDic];

   }
}
```

Comment: this is the better solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the textfields by iterating through the subview array of the scrollview

```
for (UIView *subView in scrollview) {
    //check if the subView is a textfield by for example matching a certain tag
    //save text of textfield
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating textField then assign tagValue to every textField and then access textField using tag value....

```
UITextField *txtField = (UITextField *) [scrollView viewWithTag:tag];
```